# Timer interpretation

Tags: stata

If i run Stata's timer:

```
timer on 1 
(code lines)
timer off 1
timer list 1
```

I cannot read the result:

```
timer list 1
1:    325.15 /        2 =     162.5725
```

The next time the timer produces:

```
timer list 1
1:    622.47 /        3 =     207.4883
```

It seems it is dividing 325.15 by 2, dividing 622.47 by 3.

Why? What does pre-division number mean? What does post-division number mean?

I tried reading the [manual on the topic](https://www.stata.com/manuals/ptimer.pdf) and other information online but I couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is the time elapsed in seconds and the second is the number of times the timer was turned on and off.

Using the example from the help file:

```
program tester
    version 13
    forvalues repeat=1(1)100 {
        timer on 1
        quietly summarize price
        timer off 1
    }
    timer list 1
    return list
end
```

And the toy dataset `auto.dta`:

```
sysuse auto, clear
timer clear 1  

tester
   1:      0.01 /      100 =       0.0001

scalars:
                  r(N) =  74
              r(sum_w) =  74
               r(mean) =  6165.256756756757
                r(Var) =  8699525.974268788
                 r(sd) =  2949.495884768919
                r(min) =  3291
                r(max) =  15906
                r(sum) =  456229
                 r(t1) =  .008
                r(nt1) =  100

tester
   1:      0.02 /      200 =       0.0001

scalars:
                  r(N) =  74
              r(sum_w) =  74
               r(mean) =  6165.256756756757
                r(Var) =  8699525.974268788
                 r(sd) =  2949.495884768919
                r(min) =  3291
                r(max) =  15906
                r(sum) =  456229
                 r(t1) =  .017
                r(nt1) =  200
```

If you clear the timer again:

```
timer clear 1

tester
   1:      0.01 /      100 =       0.0001

scalars:
                  r(N) =  74
              r(sum_w) =  74
               r(mean) =  6165.256756756757
                r(Var) =  8699525.974268788
                 r(sd) =  2949.495884768919
                r(min) =  3291
                r(max) =  15906
                r(sum) =  456229
                 r(t1) =  .007
                r(nt1) =  100
```